# Conditional color and mark style for scatter plot in PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, groupplots

I have a data file that has two columns each containing a class, one for color (`QoI`) and one for marker type (`type`). I would like points that have have the same `QoI` value be the same color, but have a different marker type for each `type`. There are only two different value for `type`, but several for `QoI`. I can get the colors working, but cannot figure out how to incorporate different marker styles. I couldn't find a way to use multiple values of `meta`, but perhaps there's another solution.

There are multiple plots that will be reading from multiple files, though for the MWE below they all read the same data. I just want to make sure the solution also works with `groupplots`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} % LATEX and plain TEX
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Dark2}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
  QoI model surrogate type outname QoI_group error_scaled
  1 -1 -1.01224658575 training Q1 1 0.014956929466
  1 -0.977952092966 -0.984618496392 training Q1 1 0.014956929466
  2 0.53568190987 0.521776331357 training Q2 1 0.0158105026132
  3 0.798208448928 0.789090773894 training Q3 1 0.044540998773
  4 0.378407928561 0.326243792219 training Q4 1 0.0274695358287
  4 0.355049936935 0.33464474407 training Q4 1 0.0274695358287
  3 0.762183505103 0.681415197111 validation Q3 1 0.044540998773
  3 0.822636091166 1.02086372811 validation Q3 1 0.044540998773
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
  \tikzset{mark options={mark size=2, opacity=0.5}}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by 1, horizontal sep=1em},
    width=7cm, height=7cm,
    ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2, xmin=-1.2, xmax=1.2,
    scatter/classes={1={Dark2-A}, 2={Dark2-B}, 3={Dark2-C}, 4={Dark2-D}},
    scatter,
    scatter src=explicit symbolic,
    ]
    \nextgroupplot[title={1}]
    \addplot[only marks] table[x=model, y=surrogate, meta=QoI] {data.dat};
    \nextgroupplot[title={2}, yticklabels={,,}]
    \addplot[only marks] table[x=model, y=surrogate, meta=QoI] {data.dat};
    \nextgroupplot[title={3}, yticklabels={,,}]
    \addplot[only marks] table[x=model, y=surrogate, meta=QoI] {data.dat};    
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Figure generated by MWE]

## Response to answer addendum

I added some comments to the code below to make more clear what I am trying to achieve. I think I was mistaken, I thought you could "cycle" through colors /based on/ the values of `QoI`. If that is not the case, do I have to explicitly define the `scatter/classes`? I could not find an example in the manual, so perhaps that is what is needed.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} % LATEX and plain TEX
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Dark2}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{training}{
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{2pt}\pgfusepathqfillstroke}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{validation}{
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-2pt}{-1pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2pt}{-1pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{2pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-2pt}{-1pt}}
  \pgfusepathqfillstroke}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
  QoI model surrogate type outname QoI_group error_scaled
  1 -1 -1.01224658575 training Q1 1 0.014956929466                      % Color 1, mark style 1 (until "type"="validation")
  1 -0.977952092966 -0.984618496392 training Q1 1 0.014956929466        % Color 1
  2 0.53568190987 0.521776331357 training Q2 1 0.0158105026132          % Color 2
  3 0.798208448928 0.789090773894 training Q3 1 0.044540998773          % Color 3
  4 0.378407928561 0.326243792219 training Q4 1 0.0274695358287         % Color 4
  4 0.355049936935 0.33464474407 training Q4 1 0.0274695358287          % Color 4
  3 0.762183505103 0.681415197111 validation Q3 1 0.044540998773        % Color 3, mark style 2
  3 0.822636091166 1.02086372811 validation Q3 1 0.044540998773         % Color 3, mark style 2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
  \tikzset{mark options={mark size=2, opacity=0.5}}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by 1, horizontal sep=1em},
    width=7cm, height=7cm,
    ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2, xmin=-1.2, xmax=1.2,
    % Commenting out scatter/classes removes meta color coding.
    % Is there a way that I can automatically cycle the colors in scatter/classes
    % so I don't have to define each explicitly, and so they'll reset for each \addplot+?
    scatter/classes={1={Dark2-A}, 2={Dark2-B}, 3={Dark2-C}, 4={Dark2-D}},
    scatter,
    scatter src=explicit symbolic,
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{type}  \as \Type},
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{QoI}  \as \QoI},
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark=\Type},
    % point meta=\coordindex     % This wasn't needed.
    ]
    \nextgroupplot[title={1}]
    \addplot[only marks] table[x=model, y=surrogate, meta=QoI] {data.dat};
    \nextgroupplot[title={2}, yticklabels={,,}]
    \addplot[only marks] table[x=model, y=surrogate, meta=QoI] {data.dat};
    \nextgroupplot[title={3}, yticklabels={,,}]
    \addplot[only marks] table[x=model, y=surrogate, meta=QoI] {data.dat};    
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image from updated code.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405778/121799) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185382/121799). You only need to name your symbols somehow and use them like in the example of page 402 of the pgfplots manual. That is, you can use `visualization depends on` and then change the symbols with `scatter/@pre marker code`. **UPDATE**: I dropped the definition of the symbols, which I did for fun (and I stressed that). I do not think that discarding some part of the data and using `\addplot` over and over is very elegant.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} % LATEX and plain TEX
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\pgfplotsset{colormap/Dark2,
cycle list/Dark2,
    }

\pgfdeclareplotmark{training}{\pgfuseplotmark{*}}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{validation}{\pgfuseplotmark{square}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
  QoI model surrogate type outname QoI_group error_scaled
  1 -1 -1.01224658575 training Q1 1 0.014956929466                      % Color 1, mark style 1 (until "type"="validation")
  1 -0.977952092966 -0.984618496392 training Q1 1 0.014956929466        % Color 1
  2 0.53568190987 0.521776331357 training Q2 1 0.0158105026132          % Color 2
  3 0.798208448928 0.789090773894 training Q3 1 0.044540998773          % Color 3
  4 0.378407928561 0.326243792219 training Q4 1 0.0274695358287         % Color 4
  4 0.355049936935 0.33464474407 training Q4 1 0.0274695358287          % Color 4
  3 0.762183505103 0.681415197111 validation Q3 1 0.044540998773        % Color 3, mark style 2
  3 0.822636091166 1.02086372811 validation Q3 1 0.044540998773         % Color 3, mark style 2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
  \tikzset{mark options={mark size=2, opacity=0.5}}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by 1, horizontal sep=1em},
    width=7cm, height=7cm,
    ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2, xmin=-1.2, xmax=1.2,
    scatter,
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{type}  \as \Type},
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{QoI}  \as \QoI},
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark=\Type},
    point meta=explicit
    ]
    \nextgroupplot[title={1}]
    \addplot[only marks] table[x=model, y=surrogate, meta=QoI] {data.dat};
    \nextgroupplot[title={2}, yticklabels={,,}]
    \addplot[only marks] table[x=model, y=surrogate, meta=QoI] {data.dat};
    \nextgroupplot[title={3}, yticklabels={,,}]
    \addplot[only marks] table[x=model, y=surrogate, meta=QoI] {data.dat};    
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks again! Is it possible to autocycle through the colors? It seems like I have to apply them through `scatter/classes` in order for it to take effect.

Comment: @chasely As far as understand, these cycle lists allow you to switch colors from plot to plot, that is, each `\addplot` comes with a new color (see section 4.7.7 of the pgfplots manual). Or are you looking for the `scatter/use mapped color = {color=mapped color}` option?

Comment: It does indeed cycle through colors for each `\addplot+`, but can I cycle through colors for the `meta` flags without specifying each in `scatter/classes`? I need to specify `scatter` in order to get the `\Type` to trigger the mark style, but this also requires me to specify the `scatter/classes` for each item in `\QoI`. I can do this, but I have ~40 different classes (and growing) and would like to auto-generate these plots as I add more data.

Comment: @chasely I still do not understand what you want, but I added a second code. Please have a look. The reason why I do not understand your question is that in my mind "cycle" clashes with the assumption that the color should depend on QoI. Or do you just want to define a color map?

Comment: I added a response in my original question. I do want the color to depend on QoI, but want to avoid explicitly defining each of the mappings from QoI->color via `scatter/classes`. I added a few comments to the updated code that should clarify what I am trying to achieve, but I am not sure if what I want is possible.

Comment: @chasely I added another iteration.

Comment: It appears that it is coloring them based on their y-value instead of QoI, i.e., the three points in the top right of the plots should all be the same color, with two of the three having the triangle shape. I'm thinking this may not be worth the trouble to figure out, since I can just manually specify the colors through `scatter/classes` and get the results I want. Doing that is probably going to be faster than trying to find the right trigger within the code :)

Comment: @chasely I think NOW I understand. Could you please have a look at my update?

Comment: Yes that works perfectly! I was missing the `colormap/Dark2` and `point meta=explicit`, that did the trick!

Comment: @chasely Well, I updated my solution. Stefan Pinnow made you believe that you have to define your own symbols, which is not the case. I stressed that I did that only for fun. Sorry if that was confusing. And I do not believe that using `\addplot` over and over is too elegant.

Comment: I keep going back and forth with accepted answers, I'm sticking with yours since it's cleaner on compilation. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here I present a solution where you don't have to define markers that match the "type" entry in your data file. If the default markers don't match your taste feel free to define your own (marker) `cycle list` using e.g. `\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist`.

For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
    QoI model   surrogate   type        outname QoI_group   error_scaled
    1   -1      -1.01224659 training    Q1      1           0.014956929466
    1   -0.9780 -0.98461850 training    Q1      1           0.014956929466
    2   0.53568 0.521776331 training    Q2      1           0.0158105026132
    3   0.79821 0.789090774 training    Q3      1           0.044540998773
    4   0.37841 0.326243792 training    Q4      1           0.0274695358287
    4   0.35505 0.334644744 training    Q4      1           0.0274695358287
    3   0.76218 0.681415197 validation  Q3      1           0.044540998773
    3   0.82264 1.020863728 validation  Q3      1           0.044540998773
    \end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        pgfplots.colorbrewer,
        pgfplots.groupplots,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        % load a colormap that fits your needs
        colormap/Dark2,
        % create a custom colormap from the colors of above loaded colormap ...
        colormap={test}{
            % using the first x colors, corresponding the max "QoI" value
            % (to avoid an error if the number is too big)
            samples of colormap=(4)
        },
        % we want to use "constant" colors in the colormap
        % (i.e. don't interpolate between colors)
        colormap access=const,
        % create a filter for symbolic values
        % (borrowed from <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58563/95441>)
        discard if not/.style 2 args={
            % suppress LOG messages about the filtered points
            filter discard warning=false,
            x filter/.code={
                \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
                \edef\tempb{#2}
                \ifx\tempa\tempb
                \else
                    \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
                \fi
            },
        }
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\small,
]
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group size=3 by 1,
            horizontal sep=1em,
            % (added this option, so you don't have to provide the
            %  `yticklabels' at the `\nextgroupplot' options)
            yticklabels at=edge left,
        },
        width=7cm,
        height=7cm,
        ymin=-1.2,
        ymax=1.2,
        xmin=-1.2,
        xmax=1.2,
        scatter,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % moved common options here
        /tikz/only marks,
        table/x=model,
        table/y=surrogate,
        table/meta=QoI,
        point meta=explicit,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]
    \nextgroupplot[title={1}]
        % cycle through the possible "type" entries
        % (because every new `\addplot' command uses the next entry in the
        %  `cycle list', the markers are changed as you wish)
        \foreach \i in {training,validation} {
            \addplot+ [discard if not={type}{\i}] table {data.dat};
        }
    \nextgroupplot[title={2}]
        \foreach \i in {training,validation} {
            \addplot+ [discard if not={type}{\i}] table {data.dat};
        }
    \nextgroupplot[title={3}]
        \foreach \i in {training,validation} {
            \addplot+ [discard if not={type}{\i}] table {data.dat};
        }
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: This is an elegant solution. However I get a note when compiling: "`NOTE: coordinate (a,b) has been dropped because it is unbounded (in x). (see also unbounded coords=jump).` Where `a,b` are the x and y coordinates. The warning goes away by adding in `unbounded coords=jump`, but I don't see why this would show up. I'm using PGFPlots 1.15 (On MacTex 2017). Perhaps this isn't an issue with 1.16. In any case, it does plot all the data even with the warning.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out that it's due to the exclusion.

Comment: You are absolutely right.