# pgfplots: shared Y-axis plot with three sub plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

The example below has 3 (technically 6) separate plots that share a common Y-axis. I've seen many examples of shared x-axis, but I cannot figure out how to do 3 like below in pgfplots.

Note I would like the three plots to appear attached to each other like in the example.
[image: Example from Tableau]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427065/95441 and set `horizontal sep=0pt`. Does that help?

Comment: That does indeed! Thank you very much. I have searched everywhere to no avail. I feel silly now

Comment: Not a problem. You are new to this site and thus have a n00bie bonus ;) If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) it (by clicking on the arrows next to the score).